# Hibernate Mapping using xml without creating table from hibernate framework

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am a totally beginner student in hibernate. I read tutorials available in various websites but actually I can't understand hibernate mapping using XML without creating table from hibernate framework.

Can anybody help me in hibernate mapping (one_to_one) using XML with MySQL database by creating required tables using MySQL queries in simple way?

Answer (score 0):

I used this website to go through the tutorial. It helped a lot for clearing up my basic hibernate questions.
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/

Comment: Could you please give me explanation about one to one xml mapping